# Applying set operations on subsets of $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 8, 9\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set Operation-

Let A={2,4,5,6,8} B={1,4,5,9} and c={x| E Z{positive Integer} and 2 <= x <5 } of S={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

compute each of the following sets:

**(c ∩ B)∪ ¬A**

my answer:

C={0,1,2}

C ∩ B= {1}

¬A={0,1,3,7,9}

(c ∩ B)∪ ¬A = {0,1,3,7,9}

**¬{B - A} ∩ (A - B)**

¬{B - A}={0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
(A - B)={2,6,8}

¬{B - A} ∩ (A - B)= {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

is this correct? also does any one know an online calculator I can verify these sets operations with . thank you

Comment: Try again: $C=\{2, 3, 4\}$

Comment: How so- C is less or equal to 2 and C is less then five and C is a positive integers - actually I think C should be C={0,1,2}. but how did you get the 3 and 4 thanks

Comment: C is the set of all integers x *such that* $2\leq x \lt 5$. That means any integer greater than or equal to 2, but less than 5, belongs to $C$. Put differently, $x\in C$ means that $x$ is between 2 and 5, inclusive of 2, excluding 5.

Comment: I read this as, any integer that is less or equal to 2 and less then five?

Comment: $2 \leq x \iff x \geq 2$.

Comment: ahh yes of course. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first, you got off to a bad start, since $$C =\{x\mid x \in \mathbb Z, 2\leq x \lt 5\} = \{2, 3, 4\}$$

In the second, you did fine until the end: you erred on your last step. You are being asked what the **intersection** of the two sets, not their union: $$\lnot(B-A) \cap (A-B) = \{2, 6, 8\}$$